# Ticket for Mont des Arts (Kunstberg)

Tags: belgium, brussels

I am searching for ticket price for entering Mont des Arts (Kunstberg) in Brussels. Does anyone know how much it costs to enter the flower garden? 
I would like to just enter the garden, without having a tour-guided walk.
I did not find the info on Internet. Is the place open to the public for free?

Answer (score 3):

Mont des Arts/Kunstberg is an area containing many museums and other attractions. Those museums/galleries/etc generally require tickets, but the flower garden is a publicly-accessible space with no tickets or entry fees.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful. Yes i mean the flower garden only, i have seen  http://www.montdesarts.com/ but they only explain ticket for the museums.

Answer (score -2):

Is think this is it: http://www.montdesarts.com/

And on this page: http://www.montdesarts.com/en/contact/Brussels-Card
... it says this:

> For more information on sales outlets and prices, go to: https://visit.brussels/en/sites/brusselscard/
>
> [www.brusselscard.be](https://visit.brussels/en/sites/brusselscard/)

It looks like that the Brussels-card give you access to [40 museums](https://visit.brussels/en/sites/brusselscard/listpage/brussels-card-museums), but it doesn't say anything about Kunstberg (which is wierd, since it's mentioned on Kunstbergs website).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Zeth. I see you're having a bit of a rough go, with down votes and certain comments. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, and looks for info that is specific in both what is asked and the response. Stick with it, keep participating, and [take the Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to best to contribute :)